# Multiple populates - mongoosejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Just a simple query, for example with a double ref in the model.

**Schema / Model**

```
var OrderSchema = new Schema({

    user: {
        type    : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref     : 'User',
        required: true
    },

    meal: {
        type    : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref     : 'Meal',
        required: true
    },
});

var OrderModel = db.model('Order', OrderSchema);
```

**Query**

```
OrderModel.find()
    .populate('user') // works
    .populate('meal') // dont works
    .exec(function (err, results) {
         // callback
    });
```

I already tried something like

```
.populate('user meal')
.populate(['user', 'meal'])
```

In fact only one of the populates works.

So, how do is get two populates working ?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You're already using the correct syntax of:

```
OrderModel.find()
    .populate('user')
    .populate('meal')
    .exec(function (err, results) {
         // callback
    });
```

Perhaps the `meal` ObjectId from the order isn't in the `Meals` collection?

Answer (score 48):

**UPDATE:**
This solution remains for the version 3.x of Mongoose 
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/3.8.x/docs/populate.html 
 but is no longer documented for >= 4.x versions of Mongoose and so the answer from @JohnnyHK is the only valid one for now on.

**ORIGINAL POST**
If you're using Mongoose >= 3.6, you can pass a space delimited string of the path names to populate:

```
OrderModel.find()
    .populate('user meal')
    .exec(function (err, results) {
         // callback
    });
```

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Answer (score 26):

This has probably been resolved already, but this is my take on multiple & deep population in Mongodb > 3.6:

```
OrderModel.find().populate([{
    path: 'user',
    model: 'User'
}, {
    path: 'meal',
    model: 'Meal'
}]).exec(function(err, order) {
    if(err) throw err;
    if(order) {
        // execute on order
        console.log(order.user.username); // prints user's username
        console.log(order.meal.value);    // you get the idea
    }
});
```

There are probably other ways to do this, but this makes very readable code for beginners (like me)

Comment: putting an array in the call to populate is very readable. FWIW You don't need the model unless you might want to call different ones. `.populate([{path: 'user'}, {path: 'meal'}])`

Answer (score 18):

You can use `array` syntax:

```
let results = await OrderModel.find().populate(['user', 'meal']);
```

You can also select which properties you want from each populate:

```js
let results = await OrderModel.find().populate([{path: 'user', select: 'firstname'}, {path: 'meal', select: 'name'}]);
```

Answer (score 14):

The best solution in my opinion is arrays when you are populating more than one foreign field on the same level. My code shows that I have multiple populates for different levels.

```
const patients = await Patient.find({})
                    .populate([{
                        path: 'files',
                        populate: {
                            path: 'authorizations',
                            model: 'Authorization'
                        },
                        populate: {
                            path: 'claims',
                            model: 'Claim',
                            options: {
                                sort: { startDate: 1 }
                            }
                        }
                    }, {
                        path: 'policies',
                        model: 'Policy',
                        populate: {
                            path: 'vobs',
                            populate: [{
                                path: 'benefits'
                            }, {
                                path: 'eligibility', 
                                model: 'Eligibility'
                            }]
                        }
                    }]);
```

As you can see, wherever I needed more than one field of a document populated, I encased the populate key in an array and provided an array of objects, each object having a different path. Most robust and concise way to do it, in my opinion.

Answer (score 9):

Latest mongoose `v5.9.15`
has ability to take array of populate fields
so you can do,

```
.populate([ 'field1', 'field2' ])
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try:

```
OrderModel.find()
    .populate('user')
    .populate('meal')
    .exec(function (err, results) {
         // callback
    });
```

or with array options

```
OrderModel.find()
    .populate([
      {
        path: "path1",
        select: "field",
        model: Model1
      },
      {
        path: "path2",
        select: "field2",
        model: Model2
      }
    ])
    .exec(function (err, results) {
         // callback
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

**In model file do something like:-**

```
 doctorid:{
        type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'doctor'
        },
    clinicid:{
        type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'baseClinic'
        }
```

**In js file for adding operator use Something like:-**

```
 const clinicObj = await BaseClinic.findOne({clinicId:req.body.clinicid})
 const doctorObj = await Doctor.findOne({ doctorId : req.body.doctorid}) ;
**and add data as:-**
const newOperator = new Operator({
      clinicid:clinicObj._id,
      doctorid: doctorObj._id
    });
```

**Now, while populating**

```
apiRoutes.post("/operator-by-id", async (req, res) => {
    const id = req.body.id;
    const isExist = await Operator.find({ _id: id }).populate(['doctorid','clinicid'])
    if (isExist.length > 0) {
      res.send(isExist)
    } else {
      res.send("No operator found");
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem , but my mistake not in populate , i have an error in Model

if you do this

uncorrected

```
user: {
 type: [Schema.Types.ObjectId],
 ref: 'User'
}
```

correct

```
user: [{
 type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
 ref: 'User'
}]
```

you must put array around of object like this

Answer (score 0):

To populate multiple fields with array of objects in controller/action function, model of both is already referred in schema of post

```
post.find({}).populate('user').populate('comments').exec(function (err,posts)
    {
    
    if(err)
    {
        console.log("error in post");
    }
    
        return  res.render('home',{
            h1:"home Page",
            posts:posts,
            
            });      
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to the nested population you can visit [official docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate_multiple_documents)

Copied from doc page:

```
User.
  findOne({ name: 'Val' }).
  populate({
    path: 'friends',
    // Get friends of friends - populate the 'friends' array for every friend
    populate: { path: 'friends' }
  });
```

Comment: This is wrong, the question is not asking to do vertical/nested population, but rather horizontal population.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best way of doing it but i found this working too:

```
// Populate being an array of string ['company', 'user'] for exemple
const req = this.collection.findOne(filters);
  populate.forEach((el) => {
    req.populate(el);
  });
  return req.exec();
```

Allowing to delay the db call and programmatically add populates from a controller.