# Mongoose: ObjectId Array not populating

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/TestThis');
const db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', async () => {
    const userRoles = new mongoose.Schema({
        roleName: String,
        user: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}
    });
    const UserRoleModel = mongoose.model('UserRole', userRoles, 'UserRole');

    const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name: String,
        roles: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'UserRole'}]
    });
    const UserModel = mongoose.model('User', userSchema, 'User');

    await UserModel.remove({});
    await UserRoleModel.remove({});

    const user = new UserModel({
        name: 'User1'
    });

    const savedUser = await user.save();

    const role = new UserRoleModel({
        roleName: 'Test',
        user: savedUser._id
    });

    await role.save();

    const users = await UserModel.find().populate('roles').exec();
    // Does not populate roles
    console.log('Users', users);

    const roles = await UserRoleModel.find().populate('user').exec();
    // Populates the user
    console.log('Roles', roles);

    process.exit();
});
```

I'm able to populate the User when I retrieve all the roles. But I'm not able to retrieve all the Roles that belong to a User.

The code should be able to be run as long as you have mongo running and transpile it into ES5.

Is anyone able to see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple populates - mongoosejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12821596/multiple-populates-mongoosejs)

Comment: That link you sent is not using an Array, but a singular reference instead.

Answer (score 0):

(Im working along with Cody) The issue was that we were not storing the ID's of the roles in the User Model. We had mistakenly assumed that the populate method would use the User models `_id` to fetch the UserRole. That isn't the case. By adding the UserRole IDs to the `roles` array, populating worked.