# How to populate 2 ids in an object of an array Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, populate, mongoose-populate

I want to populate productId and distributor.
following is the array in my schema:

```
  products: [
    {
        productId: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            ref: 'companyProduct'
        },
        quantity: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        distributor: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            ref: 'distributor'
        }
    }
],
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple populates - mongoosejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12821596/multiple-populates-mongoosejs)

Comment: since products is an array in your schema, you need deep population: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50301562/4718434